# cakePHP HABTM find with conditions

Tags: cakephp

I have the following relationships set up:

Teacher:

```
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Classroom' => array(
        'className' => 'Classroom',
        'joinTable' => 'classrooms_teachers',
        'foreignKey' => 'teacher_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'classroom_id',
        'unique' => true,
    )
);
```

Classroom:

```
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Teacher' => array(
        'className' => 'Teacher',
        'joinTable' => 'classrooms_teachers',
        'foreignKey' => 'classroom_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'teacher_id',
        'unique' => true,
    )
);  

var $hasMany = array(
'Student' => array(
        'className' => 'Student',
        'foreignKey' => 'classroom_id',
        'dependent' => false,
    ),
);
```

Student:

```
    var $belongsTo = array(
    'Classroom' => array(
        'className' => 'Classroom',
        'foreignKey' => 'classroom_id',
    ),
  );
```

I am trying to create a dashboard for the teachers, where all students associated with the teacher through the classroom are displayed.

I am using the following find operation:

```
    $students = $this->Teacher->Classroom->find('all', array(
                                        'conditions' => array('Classroom.teacher_id' => $this->Access->getTeacherId()),
    ));
```

However, I am getting an error: `Unknown column 'Classroom.teacher_id' in 'where clause'`

I must be doing something wrong because cake is not doing the associations.

Any ideas?

Comment: Funny story, I was looking for a solution to my problem, googled "HABTM conditions" and found this. Funny part? I have a Teacher, Student and a Schoolclass Model :-/ kinda scary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the best way. Just use containable and find('first'), you don't need find all:

> ```
> $students = $this->Teacher->find('first', array(
>        'conditions' => array('Teacher.id' => $this->Access->getTeacherId()),
>        'contain' => array('Classroom'=>array('Student'))
> ));
> ```

That will get you all the classrooms associated with the teacher, and all students in those classrooms.

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct way of achieving this:

```
        $this->Teacher->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('ClassroomsTeachers')));

    $students = $this->Teacher->find('all', array(
                                        'conditions' => array('ClassroomsTeachers.teacher_id' => $this->Access->getTeacherId()),
                                        'recursive' => 2
    ));
```

I hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I made a behavior to solve the HABTM problem.

Posted my answer here:

[HABTM Find with CakePHP 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138150/habtm-find-with-cakephp-2-0/15316824#15316824)